# Print some text before a function text in Python

Tags: python-3.x

## Input code:

```
d="Good Dawn"
m="Good Morning"
a="Good Afternoon"
e="Good evenning"
n="Good Night"
nn="Good Noon"

print("What is time in only Hour?")
t=int(input("Hour: "))

def myFunc1():
    if t>4:
        print(d)
    elif t>6:
        print(m)
    elif t>11:
        print(nn)
    elif t>15:
        print(a)
    elif t>16:
        print(e)
    else:
        print(n)
print("1st Algorithm Result is: ")
myFunc1()

def myFunc2():
    if t<7:
        print(d)
    elif t<12:
        print(m)
    elif t<16:
        print(nn)
    elif t<18:
        print(a)
    elif t<20:
        print(e)
    else:
        print(n)

        
print("2nd Algorithm Result is: ")
myFunc2()
```

## The output result is:

What is time in only Hour?
Hour: 11
1st Algorithm Result is:
Good Dawn
2nd Algorithm Result is:
Good Morning

## But I want The result will be like this:

What is time in only Hour?

Hour:  11

1st Algorithm Result is: Good Dawn

2nd Algorithm Result is: Good Morning

Comment: So the only difference is the line breaks? if so, just insert at the end of each print a `\n`.

For example: `print("What is time in only Hour?\n")`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It should print with new lines per the 'But I want The result will be like this' so its not clear what is being asked.